# Extract sub-directory name from URL in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, url, path

I want to be able to extract the name of a sub-directory of a URL and save it to a string from the server-side in ASP.NET C#.  For example, lets say I have a URL that looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/default.aspx
```

How would I get the value 'directory2' from the URL?

Comment: You may want to be a little more precise: You want the last subdir before the page? ie if the url was `http://www.abc.com/foo/bar/baz/default.aspx` you'd want `baz`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Uri class has a property called [segments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments):

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/default.aspx");
Request.Url.Segments[2]; //Index of directory2
```

Comment: +1 best to avoid string splitting/parsing when there's something handy like Uri. OP didn't specify if he always wanted the last subdir - maybe you could throw in an alternative for this case.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use .LastIndexOf("/") and work backwards from that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a sorther code:

```
string url = (new Uri(Request.Url,".")).OriginalString
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` method of `string` class to split it on `/`

Try this if you want to pick page directory

```
string words = "http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/default.aspx";
string[] split = words.Split(new Char[] { '/'});
string myDir=split[split.Length-2]; // Result will be directory2
```

Here is example from MSDN. How to use `split` method.

```
using System;
public class SplitTest
{
  public static void Main() 
  {
     string words = "This is a list of words, with: a bit of punctuation" +
                           "\tand a tab character.";
     string [] split = words.Split(new Char [] {' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' });
     foreach (string s in split) 
     {
        if (s.Trim() != "")
            Console.WriteLine(s);
     }
   }
 }
// The example displays the following output to the console:
//       This
//       is
//       a
//       list
//       of
//       words
//       with
//       a
//       bit
//       of
//       punctuation
//       and
//       a
//       tab
//       character
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use System.Uri to extract the segments of the path. For example:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var uri = new System.Uri("http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Then the property "uri.Segments" is a string array (string[]) containing 4 segments like this: ["/", "directory1/", "directory2/", "default.aspx"].